# how do i revert an pip upgrade

Tags: python, pip

I did the following command just now,

```
pip install --upgrade ipykernel
```

However, i got

```
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (5.3.4)
Collecting ipykernel
  Downloading ipykernel-6.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 125 kB 4.3 MB/s 
Collecting ipython<8.0,>=7.23.1
  Downloading ipython-7.29.0-py3-none-any.whl (790 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 790 kB 9.2 MB/s 
Collecting debugpy<2.0,>=1.0.0
  Downloading debugpy-1.5.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.9 MB 126.8 MB/s 
Collecting matplotlib-inline<0.2.0,>=0.1.0
  Downloading matplotlib_inline-0.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting traitlets<6.0,>=5.1.0
  Downloading traitlets-5.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (102 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 102 kB 20.5 MB/s 
...
    Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from jupyter-client<8.0->ipykernel) (2.8.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pexpect>4.3->ipython<8.0,>=7.23.1->ipykernel) (0.7.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython<8.0,>=7.23.1->ipykernel) (0.2.5)
    Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1->jupyter-client<8.0->ipykernel) (1.15.0)
    Installing collected packages: traitlets, matplotlib-inline, ipython, debugpy, ipykernel
      Attempting uninstall: traitlets
        Found existing installation: traitlets 5.0.5
        Uninstalling traitlets-5.0.5:
          Successfully uninstalled traitlets-5.0.5
      Attempting uninstall: ipython
        Found existing installation: ipython 7.22.0
        Uninstalling ipython-7.22.0:
          Successfully uninstalled ipython-7.22.0
      Attempting uninstall: ipykernel
        Found existing installation: ipykernel 5.3.4
        Uninstalling ipykernel-5.3.4:
          Successfully uninstalled ipykernel-5.3.4
    ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
    spyder 4.2.5 requires pyqt5<5.13, which is not installed.
    spyder 4.2.5 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13, which is not installed.
    conda-repo-cli 1.0.4 requires pathlib, which is not installed.
    Successfully installed debugpy-1.5.1 ipykernel-6.5.0 ipython-7.29.0 matplotlib-inline-0.1.3 traitlets-5.1.1
```

I would like to revert my command, since some of my codes suddenly does not work
. Is it possible? Thanks!

It seems a lot fo packages are installed.

**Update**
So I actually had my `environment.yaml` from my previous `conda env export > environment.yaml`

If I do

```
conda env update --file environment.yaml --prune
```

It does not help me revert to my previous versions.... Can I force my base environment back to exactly environment.yaml?

Comment: Nothing to revert. pip didn't update anything due to dependency conflict

Comment: there is actually some upgrades done. I haven't output the complete message. It seems to have modified some of the dependencies.

Comment: In this case see casualsciences answer. It's a bit of a bummer cause you'll have to manually fix each pkg, but it'll get you where you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not believe pip keeps a history of installed packages. If you have the text output from the terminal when you did the upgrade, pip does output a list of packages that will be installed, which version you had and which version you're replacing it with. You can manually revert each package by doing

`pip uninstall <package_name> && pip install <package_name>==<version_number>`

**Edit:** Based on your edits, I suggest you repost this question in terms of your conda environment. That's a totally different system, even though it does utilize pip.

As a side note, you might be able to get away with just running

```
pip install traitlets==5.0.5
pip install ipykernel==5.3.4
pip install ipython==7.22.0
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks so much! you saved my day! I am then trying to figure out a more general methods, in case something like this happen again in the future

Comment: @hg628193hg I know you can have pip save the logs with the --log option (of course you can do the same thing manually using `tee`), thats one thing to look into as well.