# how to fix the corrupted base environment

Tags: python, pip, conda, miniconda

I accidentally install a lot of packages using `pip install -r requirements.txt` under base environment. Then I tried to `pip uninstall`, but it seems that the uninstalling process is unsuccessful.

I am using the miniconda on Windows. How can I recover the base environment to clean state? Or do I have to reinstall miniconda to remove the whole base environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Conda, [Pip doesn't seem to track revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69935875/570918) and Conda doesn't actively track what Pip does (it passively detects installed packages in the `lib/python*/site-packages`).

One idea around that conundrum might be to export a `--from-history` YAML:

```bash
conda env export -n base --from-history
```

That will include a section of `pip:` installed packages and you could use that as the list of packages to remove. It could still be problematic if, for example, Pip installed a newer version of a package from PyPI that is essential for the `conda` package to function.

If truly broken, you can also restore basic Conda functionality by using a standalone tool like Micromamba. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75381135/570918, but you'll need to check the docs for Windows installation steps.